# How to choose the correct splitted string if it match the end of original String is it possible?

Tags: java, android, logic, words

I'm having a hard time to find a solution for this issue:

```
// look we have two strings that have the same ending " day "
       String days[] = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday"};
   // but here i want nday to be choosen for Monday
   // and day for Sonday
   String splDay[] = new String[] {"Mo","Sun","day","nday"};
```

What will happen now is that the endsWith Method will pick " day " instead of " nday "

```
for (String splt: splDay)
{
    if (days[0].endsWith(splt))
    {
        //now it will pick
        Toast.makeText(this , splt , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I'm dealing with 1000 of splitted words and I want to pick the correct one that I meant it to be for the original word?
Is it possible?

Comment: You could sort `splDay` by length, starting with the longest. Can't be bothered with a full answer, but have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T:A-java.util.Comparator- if you want to try this.

Answer (score 0):

i had to do this idea :

```
String days[] = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday"};

String splDay[] = new String[] {"Mo","Sun","day","nday"};

String AnswersArray[][] = new String[][]{  {"Sun","day"} ,{"Mo", "nday"}  };
```

it's not professional way but what can i do.. that's all i got.